# Unable to install NDK side by side

Tags: android, android-ndk

While installing NDK (side by side) i am getting following error. can anyone help me to fix this error ?
bellow is the error

Packages to install:

- NDK (Side by side) 21.1.6352462 (ndk;21.1.6352462)

Preparing "Install NDK (Side by side) 21.1.6352462 (revision: 21.1.6352462)".
An error occurred while preparing SDK package NDK (Side by side) 21.1.6352462: C:\Users\ravi-9042\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk.temp\PackageOperation02\unzip\android-ndk-r21b\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\lib\python2.7\distutils\command\wininst-8.0.exe: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
.
"Install NDK (Side by side) 21.1.6352462 (revision: 21.1.6352462)" failed.
Failed packages:

- NDK (Side by side) 21.1.6352462 (ndk;21.1.6352462)